# GAS serverhandlers, what's the difference?

Tags: google-apps-script

What's the difference among

.createServerHandler, 
.createServerClickHandler, 
.createClickHandler

?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

referring to [the doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_uiinstance) *method createServerClickHandler(functionName) - deprecated 2012-03-06*

in favor of createServerHandler which creates the 'generic' server handler in the Uiinstance. The createClickHandler is one of many methods that defines the behavior of the handler : click/change/mouse/key... (see doc of the element you use) and the possible options will be different depending of the type of element.

Note that the autocomplete feature allows to see easily what handlers are available for each Ui element.

Answer (score 0):

Also important to remember, a server side handler sends your request to the server to perform the and then sends the request response back to your application, which can have some latency.

If you have a task like disabling a button immediately after it is pressed, you can use a client handler which performs the operation inside the browser and doesn't have the latency that a server handler would have.

More info: 
Handlers in general
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_user_interfaces#UIUpdate

Client handlers
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_user_interfaces#ClientHandlers

Hope that helps,

Ryan